# How do i convert a pdf file to text in apache tika

Tags: java, pdf, apache-tika

I am trying to convert a pdf file to text file using apache tika.

I am using the below code

```
curl file:////home/C:\Apache\list costs closed.pdf | java -jar  tika-app-1.6.jar --text --encoding=US-ASCII | xargs -0 >  list costs closedText
```

but when i am running this code in command promt i am getting this error.

> 'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I have already set the java environment variable.

This might sound as duplicate question , but i tried googling through other links, and i am not able to solve it. I am a beginner with this tool. So, I apologize if it sounds like duplicate.

EDIT

I tried like this

```
java -jar  C:\Apache\tika-app-1.6.jar --text C:\Apache\list costs closed.pdf
```

I get an error

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown
>   protocol: c
>           at java.net.URL.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URL.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URL.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.process(TikaCLI.java:417)
>           at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.main(TikaCLI.java:113)

Comment: Why are you using an old version of Apache Tika? Why are you trying to use Curl when the Apache Tika app will happily take a filename?

Comment: @Gagravarr could you tell me how i can do that ?

Comment: @Gagravarr could you check my edit. thats is something i tried now

Comment: Try quoting your path (or stop using Windows....)

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue you, first you have to install curl. Follow [this](https://develop.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001068567-Installing-and-using-cURL) blog.

For second issue: you have to give path with quotes. e.g.
java -jar  "C:\Apache\tika-app-1.6.jar" --text "C:\Apache\list costs closed.pdf"

You can alternatively create a local tika server on your machine and pass its address so that you don't have to load the jar file every time you want to use tika.
Server can be started using the following command in cmd: java -jar "C:\Apache\tika-server-VERSION.jar" -s
You can verify local server by going to: http://localhost:9998/

Once you have verified that server is running, you can use the below command in a new command window.
curl -T "input file path" http://localhost:9998/tika

As pointed out in the comments, Tika 1.20 is available now.